# Managing passwords in continuous deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration, teamcity

We are well into our deployment of continuous integration environment using TeamCity.  As we work through the CI process and move toward continuous deployment, we have run into a problem with how we manage production passwords.  For other changes in the config, we use the Web.Config transform.  However, I don't really want to bake the production password in a build profile.

Before CI/CD, we would take the Web.config, use aspnet_regiis to decrypt the connection strings, change the password, then re-encrypt.  Obviously, this is error prone and not at all in the spirit of CI/CD.

I've had several other thoughts that were basically all about using something in the deploy script to re-write and then encrypt the connection strings section of the file, but it seems like this must be a common problem and that there must be some generally accepted solution.  But so far, I can't find it.  Is there a "right way"?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to CD, then obviously *something* in you build/deploy chain has to know the passwords (or a proxy for the passwords).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure TeamCity with private files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721000/how-to-configure-teamcity-with-private-files)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, but that something can be the TeamCity server, which is accessed by a different set of people than your VCS.

Comment: Here is an article with an overview about why and how to avoid cleartext credentials both in code and CI/CD:
https://medium.com/twodigits/keep-passwords-out-of-source-code-why-and-how-e84f9004815a

Comment: This article covers how to manage credentials in TeamCity:
http://pinter.org/archives/3681
Note that this only provides limited security as of now, as the password is only scrambled, see:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45181

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possible solution, available since TeamCity 7.0, is to use [typed parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/What's+New+in+TeamCity+7.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity7.0-Typedbuildparameters). You can define a parameter in TeamCity of type password, and pass it somehow to your build script (either as environment variable or as your build script property).

TeamCity stores values of such parameters in its own configuration files and in database in scrambled form. If password appears in build log or on build parameters page, it will be replaced with ***.

Comment: Notice that raw password can appear in log and even TeamCity site says : 'Setting the parameter to type password does not guarantee that the raw value cannot be retrieved.'
The situation I faced: When your git push fails it prints the line 'The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request while accessing <your url>'. So if you use git url with user/password information password here won't be substituted with **** even if you typed in appropriate way

Answer (score 2):

Use config transformations.  You can even build your own transformation that can handle encryption/decryption.  The easiest way is encrypt the production strings in the release.web.config and use a transformation to handle replacing the connection strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

http://sedodream.com/2010/09/09/ExtendingXMLWebconfigConfigTransformation.aspx

If this doesn't work for you, use a postbuild event to call aspnet_regiis.  If you chose to extend the config transformation, you can do ANYTHING with it.  The encryption keys could be on the moon as long as you can get to them.

Comment: It's not that easy, where would you store encryption keys?

Comment: How about a postbuild event?  I don't know if you can do that in TeamCity, but Jenkins supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you define the connection strings IN iis. Do they change alot? I think i'd just set them in IIS for a site, and then not deploy them as part of the app, or atleast take preference of my IIS settings.

Comment: I thought that the IIS tools just provided a nice front-end to edit the application's web.config file, although I can't find documentation that confirms that now.

Comment: If you are doing continuous delivery/deployment then the build server should be responsible for the configuration of IIS also. This shouldn't be a manual step.