# Open Source .NET Project - Strong Name Key and Team City

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, strongname

I am building an Open Source Visual Studio Plug In (shameless plug [pMixins](http://www.pmixins.com)).  Because it is a Visual Studio Plug In it has to be strongly named, so I have a snk file.  I use GitHub as a source repository, but I don't want to release the snk key file to the public so I haven't added the file to GitHub.

I am trying to setup an instance of [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as a build server.  Team City is running on a dedicated machine.

How can I get a copy of my snk file into Team City?  It is not easy for me to get file system access, so I'd prefer *not* to have to copy the snk file onto the machine.  Is there a way to upload the file to the web interface, or somehow serialize it and have Team City rehydrate the file on demand for builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ([How to configure TeamCity with private files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721000/how-to-configure-teamcity-with-private-files)) 
You can create a separate private repository (on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for example) to store the snk file and then add an additional VCS Root to your Team City configuration.

Comment: I like this approach as I don't have to worry about trying to get the snk to a location where the build server can reach it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't have a key copy on the build server? It's easy:

- Use system/project/etc environment variable (`%SnkFilePath%`) inside project file `$(SnkFilePath)`
- Add condition it to be not null, not empty
- Add condition to sign only in Release mode

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459.aspx).

---

If you really want to save it to disk temporary right before build/sign, you need to write a custom build task. I'd not mess up with it.

Comment: It's not easy for me to get access to the build server file system.  Build server is hosted by IT department, and they don't like giving lowly developers access.

Comment: @ppittle: if the build agent is running under network service (or any other account having network access) you can put it on a network share. And use project-wide variable to point it out.

Comment: interesting.  Didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

You could treat your SNK as a dependency and package it in a NuGet package (to either a local network feed, or a network share).  Reference that package in your solution, and install it with TC when you build.

Totally untested, but it may be a neat workaround.

Comment: I think it will be a bit more work to create the nuget package and deploy it, but definitely thinking outside the box!